# Can you use the GPU QR factorization algorithm from cuSOLVER in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, linear-algebra, cusolver

I can see it's referenced in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/cuda_solvers.h (Geqrf), but the tensorflow QR op at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/qr_op_float.cc isn't registered for GPU usage. Can I somehow make my own op using Geqrf, or is there maybe another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/cuda_solvers.h#L160) in the source code you linked gives a hint about the current situation.

> TODO(rmlarsen, volunteers): Implement the kernels below.